# Hold Transmit Line High (EDIT Actually need TX line low and RX line high)

Tags: c#, usb

This is a pretty odd question.  I am pretty sure I have the answer, but want to make sure.  I have a unique case where I need to keep the transmit line high and receive line low.  Is there a way to do this with c#, or do I need to make this a mechanical solution?

Edit #1: Code attempt 1 to have line remain open.

```
        SerialPort serialport = new SerialPort();
        serialport.ReadTimeout = 500;
        serialport.WriteTimeout = 500;
        serialport.PortName = portName;
        serialport.BaudRate = 115200;
        serialport.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
        serialport.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
        serialport.Open();
        while (true)
        {
            serialport.Write("0xaa");
            //second attempt had the next line uncommented.
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
```

Comment: If you're pretty sure you have the answer and want to make sure, try it out and see. If it doesn't work, please post the code you tried and describe how it's not working.

Comment: This would be one of those situations of asking a question to see if someone has already tried this before and it was a failure, but locked it away (what is currently going on in many different labs across the country).  Someone may have already tried this and realized it worked/didn't work.  Why should I try something again if someone already has the answer?  If no one does I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I have never heard of a problem where the answer is either mechanical or C#. I want to see the answer.

Comment: I really wanted the answer to be C# and that's the main reason I asked.  It'd be simpler and faster to implement the fix.  Everything I've read and tried so far is pointing towards a mechanical solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most USB-to-serial adapters do not allow you to control the receive line (RX).  Sending bytes to the COM port would only control the transmit line (TX).  If you want to keep the transmit line high, you need to simply not send any bytes, because high is its default state (if we are talking about non-inverted TTL serial).

That being said, you forgot to specify what hardware you are connecting to, so it is hard to give a really specific answer that suits your needs.

Comment: Ah okay.  Discussing with some others, you have clarified this question.  Thank you a bunch.  What we were actually looking for is to hold the RX line high and the TX line low.  This will have to be a mechanical solution I believe at this point.